# How to debug problems with SQL Server multiserver (Master and Target server) administration?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, sql-server-agent

I've tried to set Mater and Target Servers on various cobinations of SQL Servers 2012 R2 on Window Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 machines but always getting one or 2 of the following errors during setting either target or master server:

- **Enlist TSX Progress**
- 1) **Create MSXOperator (always Success)**

  - Checking for an existing MSXOperator.
  - Operator does not exist. Creating.
  - Successfully created MSXOperator.
- 2) **Make sure the Agent service for '**Master-Server-Name***' is running (sometimes an Error, sometimes not)*

  - An exception occurred in SMO while trying to manage a service. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement)

    For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.3000.0+((SQL11_PCU_Main).121019-1325+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.InnerWmiException&LinkId=20476

  ---

  ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

  Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

  For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

  ---

  Invalid class  (System.Management)
- 3) Ensure the agent startup account for '**Master-Server-Name**' has rights to login as a target server (**if Success here, then 4) is error or both 3) and 4) are errors**)

  - Checking to see if the startup account for '**Target-Server-Name**' already exists. 
    Login exists on server.
  - Checking to see if login has rights to msdb.
  - Login does not have rights to msdb. Adding.
  - Created new user in msdb.
  - Checking to see if user is a member of the TargetServersRole.
  - Adding user to the TargetServersRole.
  - Added user to TargetServersRole.
- 4) Enlist '**Target-Server-Name**' into '**Master-Server-Name**' (**if Success here, then error in 3) or both in 3) and 4)**)

  - Enlisting target server 'Master-Server-Name' with master server 'NOVOSIB-1C'.
  - Using new enlistment method.

    **Messages**
  - MSX enlist failed for JobServer 'Target-Server-Name'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

    For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.3000.0+((SQL11_PCU_Main).121019-1325+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=MSX+enlist+JobServer&LinkId=20476

  ---

  ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

  An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
  (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

  ---

  The enlist operation failed (reason: SQLServerAgent Error: Unable to connect to MSX 'Target-Server-Name'.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 22026)

  For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.3128&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=22026&LinkId=20476

In all cases I was using a domainUser login with sysadmin role for setting SQL Server Agent service and owner of an SQL Server Agent job (or, in the latter, tried also `sa`), Windows Authentication to `localhost` in used by them maintenance plans. The used domainUser is part of (local) Administrators group in each of the Windows (machines).

The SQL Server Management Studio is run `As Administrator`.

How can I troubleshoot these errors?
What should I check and look for?

Specifically, I do not quite understand:

- Which server and which login to check in from the phrase:
  "Ensure the agent startup account for '**Master-Server-Name**' has rights to login as a target server (Success)"
- How to check that this login has rights for msdb from the phrase:
   *"Checking to see if login has rights to msdb"*
  -